# send multiple json objects to http server

Tags: android

In my application there is a form which has more than 50 fields. I have to send the filled form details to http server. I'm saving the form filled on submit button to my local db. A form can be filled multiple times. When the device is connected to network I have to send all the data to server. Each row I have parsed it to json object. My question is how to send these json objects? I can't use Volley, as I have to send json string not object.
Thanks.

Comment: How is it about sending a json array(as string) contains your json objects. The server have to process every object in this array as single item

Comment: In that case what will be the key

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: There will be no key(only numeric index).  But you can use a foreach or a for-counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send json objects one after other. When you receive the response from server for one json object,then send the next json object. Sending all the data in one go is not a good solution.